# Why does a body falling down follow this pattern of velocity?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, kinematics, free-fall

I was wondering about the pattern of velocity for a body falling down with initial velocity $u= 0$ and $g = 10m/s^2$.

Without using the formula , I thought :

Velocity would change in this manner (given below),
Speed in m /s:

10

20

30

40

But when I cross checked , it actually travels in different way. Displacement = 5$t^2$ ,
By assuming u = 0 ,

Distance in metres

But here only

- 5 m.
- 15 in next.

20

+25in next.

45

+35 in next .

80

5m at top shows and proof that it travelled with 5m/s velocity , even though g = 10m$s^2$.

Why is that ?

Yes , but using formula for v only it shows that v = 10m/s.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The term $a = 10m/s^2$ means that every second the velocity of the body is changing by a magnitude of $10$.

If the body is dropped then this means that **at the end of $1^{st}$ second , the body will gain a speed of $10m/s$**. It doesn't mean that for the whole duration of **0 to 1 second**, it moved with a speed of $10m/s$.

As I told earlier , it just means that the body will have a speed of $10m/s$ **at the end of $1_{st}$ second**. Similarly it can applied for further durations.

Now when you say that it travelled $5m$ in the first second, again as I said earlier it doesn't mean that the body moved with $5m/s$ for this duration. It just means that the body accelerated from rest in such a way that it covered a distance of $5m$ in this duration.

The variation in distance travelled which you noticed is because of this accelertion. If there was no gravity and the body was given a certain velocity then it would have moved with that final velocity otherwise the velocity will keep on changing and the faster you move in a duration the farther you travel in that duration.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/118166/discussion-on-answer-by-ankit-why-does-a-body-falling-down-follow-this-pattern-o).

Answer (score 1):

Let's plot:

$$ v(t) = at $$

with $a=10\,$m/s:

[image]

The distance traveled from $t=0$ is the area under the "curve"....which forms a triangle:

$$ A = \frac 1 2 b \times h $$

where the base is:

$$ b = t = 4\,{\rm seconds} $$

and the height is:

$$ h = at = 400\,{\rm m/s} $$

thus:

$$ A = \Delta x = \frac 1 2 (at)(t) = \frac 1 2 a t^2 = 800\,{\rm m} $$

Answer (score 0):

If it travelled with a uniform speed, then the velocity when the object travelled 5m is 5m/s. But the speed is increasing   continously from 0 to 10m/s.

dv/dt = a

After integrating,

v = a* t

dx/dt = v

dx = v*dt

dx = a*t dt

After integrating,

x = (1/2)a* t^2

To measure v, you have to integrate from t=0 to t=1.
So, x(in t=5)=5m

Comment: Why is not 10m /s for 1st second . Since acc = 10m/s^2 . So doesn’t it mean that for every second , there is change in velocity with 10m/s

Comment: Yes. It says 10m/s for 1st second. But the velocity is changing continously. Then, you cannot calculate distances by the method you used. Your method assumes velocity is constant for that whole second. When adding a quantity which is changing continously, you have to integrate.

Answer (score 0):

The body starts with a velocity of $0$ m/s at time $t=0$ seconds. At time $t=1$ second it has a velocity of $10$ m/s. So its *average* velocity in the first second (from $t=0$ to $t=1$) is only $\frac 1 2 (0+10) = 5$ m/s, and it travels $5$ m in this first second.

At time $t=2$ seconds its velocity is $20$ m/s. So its *average* velocity in the second second (from $t=1$ to $t=2$) is $\frac 1 2 (10+20) = 15$ m/s, and it travels $15$ m in the second second. So at time $t=2$ seconds it has travelled a total distance of $5 + 15 = 20$ m.

At time $t=3$ seconds its velocity is $30$ m/s; its *average* velocity in the third second (from $t=2$ to $t=3$) is $\frac 1 2 (20+30) = 25$ m/s; it travels $25$ m in the third second; and at time $t=3$ seconds it has travelled a total distance of $5 + 15 +25 = 45$ m.

And so on.

Comment: But even it started from t = 0, it’s acceleration was still 10m/s^2

Comment: @user284851 Yes, but this doesn't mean the body's velocity goes from $0$ to $10$ m/s. It means the body's velocity increases gradually and smoothly from $0$ m/s at $t=0$ seconds to $10$ m/s at $t=1$ second. You seem to have a basic misunderstanding about how constant acceleration works.